# Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftGlibc'

Tags: swift, linux

I have installed Swift 3.1.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine following the instructions on Swift.org. When I tried to import glibc in the REPL, errors showed up. I could not find any cases like this online. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You should copy/paste the *command* and the *error message*. You should not post screen captures in this case. The text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=path_to_swift/usr/lib/swift/clang/include/
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```